# Samba fileshare can't be seen by Win7

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, samba

I'm a novice network admin who was tasked with setting up a real simple file server for a non-profit I volunteer for. The problem is that I'm not very familiar with Linux, and for a number of reasons the best "fit" for that server will be Ubuntu. For those reasons I decided I'd try to set it up in-house and make sure I know what I'm doing before wasting my time and the company's by trying to muddle through it on-site.

I have a Win7 host running VirtualBox to virtualize an Ubuntu Server 10.4. VirtualBox is set to use a Bridged connection, and indeed DHCP is assigning it an IP in the rest of the LAN. Current network looks like:

```
+ 192.168.1.1        Router
--+ 192.168.1.3      Host Win7
--+ 192.168.1.6      Guest Ubuntu Server 10.4
```

I've set Samba up on my fileserver and the config SEEMS right. All I have is a guest access share, so authentication shouldn't be the issue. However opening `\\192.168.1.6\MyShare` gives me a standard windows "Cannot access this network resource" dialog.

[image]

For the time being I've done `sudo ufw disable` to make sure there's no firewall issues from guest to host. `sudo iptables --list` shows no rules and default `ACCEPT` on all chains.

Since I'm new to the Linux side of things -- I'm stumped. What's my next troubleshooting step?

Comment: Note: [crossposted from serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/655145/samba-filesharing-to-win7) since this is a personal project preceding a professional one.

Comment: related question http://askubuntu.com/questions/19361/cant-access-ubuntus-shared-folders-from-windows-7? <p>http://askubuntu.com/questions/12254/no-access-to-samba-shares?rq=1

Comment: With SSH enabled, is your VM accessible using it?

Comment: @DanielB I haven't enabled SSH yet, but I don't mind doing so. Give me a bit and I'll report back.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, I can SSH into my Ubuntu server from the host machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by digging deeper into my network config and making sure all the relevant ports were allowed through `ufw`. The [Ubuntu community help page for `ufw`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) was a great resource for this. For some reason just doing `sudo ufw disable` wasn't enough, I had to specifically allow those ports then it worked like a charm.

I ran the following commands as root:

```
ufw allow 137/tcp
ufw allow 137/udp
ufw allow 138/tcp
ufw allow 138/udp
ufw allow 139/tcp
ufw allow 139/udp
ufw allow 445/tcp
```